# Deploy RHEL BYOS Marketplace Image to Azure

Tags: azure, redhat, rhel, rhel7, azure-deployment

How can the BYOS images for RHEL in the Azure Marketplace be deployed to a VM?

I can see that BYOS images exist:

```
PS H:\> Get-AzureRmVMImageSku -Location centralus -PublisherName RedHat -Offer rhel-byos | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty Id


Skus          : rhel-lvm74
Offer         : rhel-byos
PublisherName : RedHat
Location      : centralus
RequestId     : 240292aa-1661-4048-9f47-b2d56e131087
StatusCode    : OK

Skus          : rhel-lvm75
Offer         : rhel-byos
PublisherName : RedHat
Location      : centralus
RequestId     : 240292aa-1661-4048-9f47-b2d56e131087
StatusCode    : OK

Skus          : rhel-raw69
Offer         : rhel-byos
PublisherName : RedHat
Location      : centralus
RequestId     : 240292aa-1661-4048-9f47-b2d56e131087
StatusCode    : OK

Skus          : rhel-raw75
Offer         : rhel-byos
PublisherName : RedHat
Location      : centralus
RequestId     : 240292aa-1661-4048-9f47-b2d56e131087
StatusCode    : OK
```

I'm also able to see that plan information is required:

```
PS H:\> Get-AzureRmVMImage -Location centralus -PublisherName RedHat -Offer rhel-byos -Skus rhel-raw75 -Version 7.5.20180917 | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty Id

Location         : centralus
PublisherName    : RedHat
Offer            : rhel-byos
Skus             : rhel-raw75
Version          : 7.5.20180917
FilterExpression :
Name             : 7.5.20180917
OSDiskImage      : {
                     "operatingSystem": "Linux"
                   }
PurchasePlan     : {
                     "publisher": "redhat",
                     "name": "rhel-raw75",
                     "product": "rhel-byos"
                   }
DataDiskImages   : []
```

However, if I try to deploy a BYOS image with the appropriate plan information, I get the following error:

> "Offer with PublisherId: redhat, OfferId: rhel-byos, PlanId rhel-raw75 is private and can not be purchased by subscritpionId:

As far as I can tell, the private offers in the marketplace [can be made available through the partner](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/private-offers-on-azure-marketplace/) (RedHat, in this case), but I can't find any Red Hat documentation for making these available.  The closest I've found [relates to the Red Hat Gold Images](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2962171), but this appears specific to AWS.

Has anyone been able to deploy the RHEL BYOS images from the Azure Marketplace?  If so, what steps am I missing to enable access to those images for deployment?

Comment: The document your find shows that the private image just available for the partner customer. "Azure Marketplace publishers are now able to create these private offers via the Cloud Partner Portal." So it seems you cannot use the private image if you are not the partner.

Answer (score 2):

The Red Hat BYOS images are offered by Microsoft and are currently part of the BYOS Preview Program.  You need to migrate your eligible, unused Red Hat subscriptions to the Cloud Access program, then sign up for the BYOS program on Microsoft's site.

I'm checking internally to see if I can share links to both programs here.  I do suggest you open a case with Red Hat so we can assist.

Answer (score 1):

Private Images are only available to customers (Subscription) that the provider (in this case RedHat) has made this available to.

Don't believe RedHat 7.5 is available for all, since you have everything setup try sku rhel-lvm74.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code blocks are coming directly from Azure, so I guess RHEL 7.5 became available.  Based on the version number, I'm guessing it's been available for about three months now.  
  
Your first statement is what I'm trying to figure out.  How do I have Red Hat make those images available?  As far as I can find, they don't document anything about it

Comment: I wouldn't say 'block' by Azure.  There are a lot of images in Azure that are not available to customer because the provider is still testing.  Some never make to the public.  Point been it might never be available in Azure for the public. You can try the redhat community maybe there is process to give you access to pre-release images.

Comment: PS: Wanted you to try known working image to make sure its not a T&C issue.

Comment: Just got time to repro, failing on all BYOL.  Looks like they have change their validation for BYOL. https://access.redhat.com/articles/3189332 . hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think these images were used for openshift. They are now "available" with a preview program where you need to request the access.

I suggest you contact your Redhat technical contact or the sales guy. They should be able to help you get info and send you the URL for the preview signup.

I'm actively trying to access this since few weeks, the workflow is not clear and nobody at redhat nor microsoft seems to know how/what/if they can do something.. My redhat solution architect has helped me a lot on this, I'm currently able to access the image after few emails back and forth but I'm still unable to sucessfully create a vm from it. I'm not sure I can share the URL for the signup to the preview program... I'll check that and post if I can.

---

Edit:
Here's how I fixed the last problem I had, it's a weird one so I'll post hoping to help someone having the same issue.

```
> az vm image list --offer rhel-byos --publisher redhat --sku rhel-lvm75 -l canadacentral --all
[
  {
    "offer": "rhel-byos",
    "publisher": "RedHat",
    "sku": "rhel-lvm75",
    "urn": "RedHat:rhel-byos:rhel-lvm75:7.5.20180509",
    "version": "7.5.20180509"
  },
...
]
```

You can see the publisher is "RedHat" notice the uppercase R and H. 
**Even if it's written like this in there, the correct way to input it is in lowercase!!!**

In my powershell test script I was using this part of code:

```
[...]
    Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -PublisherName RedHat -Offer rhel-byos -Skus rhel-lvm75 -Version latest | Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Accept
    Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id
    Set-AzureRmVMPlan -VM $vmConfig -Publisher RedHat -Product rhel-byos -Name "rhel-lvm75"
[...]
```

I got this error:

> New-AzureRmVM : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'.
>   Additional Info:'Unable to deploy from the Marketplace image. The part
>   number in the purchase information for VM
>   '/subscriptions/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/testbyos/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/test02'
>   is not as expected. Beware that the Plan object's properties are
>   case-sensitive. ' ErrorCode: VMMarketplaceInvalidInput

So the fix is to use "redhat" all lowercase as a publisher name even if the publisher is shown as "RedHat" if you list the image. Don't ask me why...

Comment: Do you have an open case with Red Hat I can take a look at?

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the followup, no I don't I worked with the local redhat tema on this and we finally got this working. The last problem was on my side, I will edit my OP in case someone hit the same bug.

Comment: @ReneJrPurcell Thanks for following up, and for the information, especially considering how long this question has been open.  Unfortunately, as a consultant, I don't have the ability to make changes my client's Red Hat account.  Like most clients, the need to deploy the BYOL RHEL images was promptly de-prioritized once the task couldn't be delegated.

Comment: @ReneJrPurcell I saw in your code snippet a property called `urn`, but it's not referenced in the ARM deployment template for virtual machines.  Was that something that also needed to be referenced?

Comment: @aydeisen nope the "-PublisherName RedHat -Offer rhel-byos -Skus rhel-lvm75 -Version latest" are really the important property plus don't forget the Set-AzureRmVMPlan and you have to accept the term too... I never used the urn property! I'm working on a blogpost, I'll update my comment with it soon.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was waiting for the permission to share the link to signup into the BYOS. So I was denied the right to publicly share the ur to signupl. I recommend you contact your redhat/microsoft rep/salesman/architect and they'll help you and give you the required information to signup.